# make mat-chip-list required and validatable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to make [mat-chip-list](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) required and validatable inside a `<mat-form-field>`.

### HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="form-field-large">
    <mat-label>Software to install</mat-label>
    <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Software selection" formControlName="items" required>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of this.ItemsList" [selectable]="this.Selectable" [removable]="this.Removable" (removed)="itemRemove(item)">
            {{item}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="this.Removable">cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
        <input placeholder="add software..." #ItemsInput [formControl]="this.ItemsCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="this.ItemsAutocomplete" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="this.KeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="itemAdd($event)">
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-autocomplete #ItemsAutocomplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="itemSelected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of this.ItemsFilter | async" [value]="item">
            {{item}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

### TS Validator

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // form playbook
    this.FormPlaybook = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately the behavior of the [mat-chip-list](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) is not like expected:

1. the `required` do not recognize when item get added to the `chip-list`
2. the `validator` do not validate wether there is an item in the `chip-list` or not

[image]

On research I do not found any advice how to handle **required** and **validation** for [mat-chip-list](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview).